# Returning outgoing and incoming edges does not show the number of edges from all vertices

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

I wanted to retrieve all the incoming and outgoing edges from all vertices from a graph, but when I query for it, only the vertices that have both types of edges (outgoing and incoming) are shown, and the ones that only have one type are not displayed. Moreover, if a vertex does not have incoming or outgoing edges, they are not shown when I query for it, but I wanted to at least show the number zero for the vertices like this.

Here is an example. I have created a graph named 'SocialNetwork'. The users and other pages are created as vertices and the edges are the messages, likes and friendship relations. There is an user that I named as 'Charlie' that has only outgoing edges.

Here is what it shows when I query only for the incoming edges:

```sql
-- incoming edges
SELECT * FROM cypher('SocialNetwork', $$
MATCH in_edge = (a)<-[ie]-(c)
RETURN a.name, label(a), count(in_edge)
$$) AS (id agtype, label agtype, in_edges agtype);

         id         |  label   | in_edges 
--------------------+----------+----------
 "Photography Club" | "Group"  | 2
 "Hiking Group"     | "Group"  | 2
 "Chicago Bulls"    | "Page"   | 2
 "David"            | "Person" | 1
 "Book Club"        | "Group"  | 2
 "Emma"             | "Person" | 2
 "Dance Class"      | "Group"  | 2
 "Frank"            | "Person" | 1
 "Bob"              | "Person" | 1
 "Gaming Group"     | "Group"  | 2
 "Grace"            | "Person" | 2
(11 rows)
```

Here is what it shows for the outgoing edges:

```sql
-- Outgoing edges
SELECT * FROM cypher('SocialNetwork', $$
MATCH out_edge = (a)-[oe]->(b)                         
RETURN a.name, label(a), count(out_edge)                
$$) AS (id agtype, label agtype, out_edges agtype);

    id     |  label   | out_edges 
-----------+----------+-----------
 "Charlie" | "Person" | 6
 "David"   | "Person" | 2
 "Emma"    | "Person" | 2
 "Alice"   | "Person" | 3
 "Frank"   | "Person" | 3
 "Bob"     | "Person" | 1
 "Grace"   | "Person" | 2
(7 rows)
```

And here is both of them:

```sql
-- People that have both
SELECT * FROM cypher('SocialNetwork', $$
MATCH out_edge = (a)-[oe]->(b), in_edge = (a)<-[ie]-(c)
RETURN a.name, label(a), count(out_edge)
$$) AS (id agtype, label agtype, in_and_out_edges agtype);

   id    |  label   | in_and_out_edges 
---------+----------+------------------
 "David" | "Person" | 2
 "Emma"  | "Person" | 4
 "Frank" | "Person" | 3
 "Bob"   | "Person" | 1
 "Grace" | "Person" | 4
(5 rows)
```

Note that Charlie's number of outgoing edges are displayed when I query for it, but the amount of incoming edges does not appear. I wanted to at least display something like:

```sql
   id      |  label   | incoming edges 
-----------+----------+------------------
 "Charlie" | "Person" | 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using vertex_stats() as in the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('SocialNetwork', $$
MATCH (u)
RETURN vertex_stats(u)
$$) AS (vertex_info agtype);
```

This shows the *in_degree*, *out_degree* and *self-loop on each vertex*

vertex_stats() is used [here](https://github.com/apache/age/blob/master/regress/expected/age_global_graph.out) in the regression tests

Comment: Thanks Zainab Saad! this `vertex_stats` function was exactly what I was looking for!